# Get Facebook group posts in PHP8 & Symfony6

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api

I wrote web app with PHP8.1 and Symfony6. I would like to get posts from group where I'm administrator but I cannot. When I use solution from doc (using CURL)

`"https://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed?limit=5&amp;access_token=EAACEdEos0..."`

I got authorization exception, cause no app ID or, using user authorization, I got null instead of object with posts.
I wanted use PHP Graph SDK but it only support PHP v5 or v7.
I was looking for answer for several days. How Can I do it without open own business?
Regards

Comment: _"I got authorization exception"_ - probably because you did not actually pass an access token - that `&amp;` in there of course needs to be a simple `&`, outside of any HTML context.

Comment: Yes, I know, but changes &amp; to & doesn't change result. Always got null object. I was trying use wordpress with existing plugins allows getting group posts and got null object too. I'm not sure but I think that is FB bug.

Comment: There are several requirements your app needs to fulfill, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#readperms

Comment: I know, as I wrote earlier I was trying using wordpress plugin with dedicated FB app, possibility to get group posts and it doesn't work too.

Comment: Whether you use a WP plugin or something else, doesn't change the fact, that your FB app behind this needs to fulfill these requirements.